# How could I optimize this pixel opacity calculation?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization, xna

I have C# code for counting pixel opacity, it is used in XNA, how I can improve it's performance?

```
    public static uint GetPixelForOpacity(uint pixelBackground, uint pixelForeground, uint pixelCanvasAlpha)
    {
        byte surfaceR = (byte)((pixelForeground & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
        byte surfaceG = (byte)((pixelForeground & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
        byte surfaceB = (byte)((pixelForeground & 0x000000FF));

        byte sourceR = (byte)((pixelBackground & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
        byte sourceG = (byte)((pixelBackground & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
        byte sourceB = (byte)((pixelBackground & 0x000000FF));

        uint newR = sourceR * pixelCanvasAlpha / 256 + surfaceR * (255 - pixelCanvasAlpha) / 256;
        uint newG = sourceG * pixelCanvasAlpha / 256 + surfaceG * (255 - pixelCanvasAlpha) / 256;
        uint newB = sourceB * pixelCanvasAlpha / 256 + surfaceB * (255 - pixelCanvasAlpha) / 256;

        return (uint)255 << 24 | newR << 16 | newG << 8 | newB;
    }
```

Comment: Calculate pixel with opacity upon background and foreground pixel.

Comment: I see. Why don't you use the built-in AlphaBlendEnable in XNA? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976070%28XNAGameStudio.31%29.aspx

Comment: I used customized BlendState() for my purpose. Now setting only Alpha on foreground image. Performance is awesome. Thanx Jonas for really good advice. I'm totaly new in XNA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use [premultiplied alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Description).
2. Videocards are made exactly to accelerate operations like this. Put your pixel data in a Texture2D and draw it to the screen with an appropriate blend mode. This will be much, much faster. Or if you don't want it on the screen right away, [redirect your rendering](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Render_to_texture.php) to another texture.

Comment: 1. I tried but when changing alpha to [0,1] divide operations take longer time  
2. This is already changing Texture2D but each pixel needs to have different opacity.

Comment: I didn't say you should use floating point values - you can use premultiplied alpha with integer values just fine. About Texture2D - you must be pretty new to graphics programming. When created with the right format, a texture keeps an alpha (opacity) value for every pixel. Read about [alpha channels](http://www.axialis.com/tutorials/tutorial-misc001.html).

Comment: Yes I'm new to graphics programming. I will consider alpha channels, looks that it can be useful for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `pixelCanvasAlpha / 256` with `pixelCanvasAlpha >> 8`. Don't divide by power of two with integer types, shift is always faster. Also, `unchecked` should help.

Comment: Replace pixelCanvasAlpha / 256 with pixelCanvasAlpha >> 8 don't help much, i think this is already improved by compiler.

Comment: I would expect the compiler to make that optimization. Just verified that it does so on Windows x64 at least.

Comment: Dammit, compilers are smart things nowadays :) How about `unchecked` effect?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it but a `bitwise not` could be faster than 255-n

```
uint newR = (sourceR * pixelCanvasAlpha + surfaceR * (uint)(byte)~pixelCanvasAlpha) >> 8;
```

or

```
uint newR = (sourceR * pixelCanvasAlpha + surfaceR * ~pixelCanvasAlpha & 0x000000FF) >> 8;
```

The only way to know is to benchmark.

Comment: The only way to know is to measure. But if casting really is slow you could `~pixelCanvasAlpha & 0x000000FF`.

Comment: Also notice that I moved the `>> 8` to the end so that it only has to be performed once.

Comment: All operations you mentioned are performed by compiler. Test shows that there is no improvement.